# How to show image in Tooltip (Bootstrap 5) / ERROR 304

Tags: javascript, image, bootstrap-5

I'm working with `Bootstrap 5`.

I have a `tooltip` where I want to display a text (which is working fine) and a image so i've used `data-bs-html="true"`.

My input incl. my `tooltip` looks like following:

```
<input
  class="form-control tooltip-element"
  data-bs-placement="right"
  data-bs-html="true"
  title="Test title.<br><img src='../assets/picture.png'>"
/>
```

When I go to `Network` I will always get `ERROR 304` because the file will be lost in the cache.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

**INFO:** Path and all values / definitions are correct.

Comment: what if you use absolute path for `img.src`. for example `https://example.com/assets/picture.png`

Comment: HTTP status code 304 is not an _error_. It is totally unclear what the actual problem is supposed to be here.

Comment: @nhy yes if I use an ```URL``` it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about `img.src`. I did create an example at [here](https://output.jsbin.com/jeginuvozi/). You can hover on input and image will show after a while

```html
  <input
  id="example"
  class="form-control tooltip-element"
  data-bs-placement="right"
  data-bs-html="true"
    title="Test title.<br><img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300'>"

/>
```

```js
var exampleEl = document.getElementById('example')
var tooltip = new bootstrap.Tooltip(exampleEl, {
  boundary: document.body,

  // read more at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#options
  template: '<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>'// or document.querySelector('#boundary')
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Actually i've tried it for my own with an ```URL``` and than it works fine. But it's not working with my local images..